# How to use A recyclerview instead of list view

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I know How you a Listview in case When we need to get the data from the internet and to show it in Listview . Now the listview is deprecated. I wanted to know how to you recyclerview instead of listview.

2nd thing I was using swipe to delete and pull to refresh in a listview , also wanted to know does recycler view support these features or not ?

please also provide the link where I can learn how to make a custom recyclerview in place of the listview

Comment: Do you not know how to use google?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!  Also show the effort you have made so far.